# Is it possible to generate a single function that handles previewKeyDown for multiple controls in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, function, events

im new programming in WPF and C#, and getting use to OOP, im trying to code my program using the best programming practices.

The program that im doing will have a lot of textboxes across the program for different input purposes, but i want to handle what you type in each textbox with a single function that applies to all textboxes across the app for easier maintenance and quick modifications if needed.

so far i achieved what i wanted for a single texbox using its events:
1-accept only numeric characters while typing
2-accept tab,arrows,backspace, del,home,end keys and ctrl+v command while typing
3-format numbers separating thousands with comma
4-accept maximum of 99,999,999
5-handle paste event, if is not numeric it pastes nothing or blank ""
6-handle paste event, if the number is bigger than 99,999,999 is set to the maximum allowed.

All of this was done with two textbox events
1-PreviewKeyDown event and
2-TextChanged event.

what i would like to achieve is to wrap all of this into a function, otherwise i will have to repeat the same code for each textbox, and if i need to update anything i will have to change all texboxes events.

all suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance

here is the code:

XAML

```
<TextBox 
x:Name="txt_startRange" 
Text="{Binding Path=MyValue, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" 
TextChanged="txt_startRange_TextChanged" 
PreviewKeyDown="txt_startRange_PreviewKeyDown" />
```

C#

```
private void txt_startRange_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     //if pasted value is not numeric it pastes empty string
     if (IsNumeric(skipComma(txt_startRange.Text)) == false)
     {
          txt_startRange.Text = "";
          return;
     }

     //if length is greater than 19 (unsigned integer 64 uses 20 characters) assumes is a greater number than UINT64 and rounds it to maximum allowed by the code
     if (txt_startRange.Text.Length > 19)
     {
          txt_startRange.Text = "99999999";
     }

     //if number is greater than maximum allowed by the code 99,999,999 it rounds it to maximum
     if (Convert.ToUInt64(skipComma(txt_startRange.Text)) >= 100000000)
     {
          txt_startRange.Text = "99999999";
     }
          
     //this function separates numbers in thousands with a comma
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_startRange.Text))
     {
          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
          int valueBefore = Int32.Parse(skipComma(txt_startRange.Text), 
 System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
          txt_startRange.Text = String.Format(culture, "{0:N0}", valueBefore);
          txt_startRange.Select(txt_startRange.Text.Length, 0);
     }

     //skipcomma function basically removes the comma from the format and converts it to int
}


private void txt_startRange_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     int key = Convert.ToInt32(e.Key);

     //Ignores everything different from 0-9, arrows, tab,backspace,del,home,end and ctr+v
     if ((key<74 || key>83) && (key<34 || key>43) && (key < 21 || key > 26) 
     && key!=2 
     && key != 32 
     && key != 3
     && key != 118
     && key != 65
     && key != 67
     || (txt_startRange.Text.Length >9 && key!=2 && key!=32 && key!=3 &&  (key < 21 || key > 26))) 
     {
          e.Handled = true;
     }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument `sender` is the instance that fired the event. In case of Controls that will be the specific control, in your case the TextBox the event is wired to.

You only need to cast to the correct type. This is how your PreviewKeyDown would go:

```
private void PreventChars_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     TextBox textbox = (TextBox) sender; //sender will have an instance to txt_startRange
     int length = textbox.Text.Length;  // use the TextBox length

     int key = Convert.ToInt32(e.Key);

     //Ignores everything different from 0-9, arrows, tab,backspace,del,home,end and ctr+v
     if ((key<74 || key>83) && (key<34 || key>43) && (key < 21 || key > 26) 
     && key!=2 
     && key != 32 
     && key != 3
     && key != 118
     && key != 65
     && key != 67
     || (length >9 && key!=2 && key!=32 && key!=3 &&  (key < 21 || key > 26))) 
     {
          e.Handled = true;
     }

}
```

Your markup will change to

```xml
<TextBox 
x:Name="txt_startRange" 
Text="{Binding Path=MyValue, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" 
TextChanged="txt_startRange_TextChanged" 
PreviewKeyDown="PreventChars_PreviewKeyDown" /> <!-- reusable eventhandler -->
```

and if you have another textbox:

```xml
<TextBox 
x:Name="txt_endRange" 
Text="{Binding Path=EndValue, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" 
TextChanged="txt_endRange_TextChanged" 
PreviewKeyDown="PreventChars_PreviewKeyDown" /> <!-- reusable eventhandler -->
```

I leave changing the other event for TextChanged as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks a lot! worked like a charm!! 
but i still have another question, the xaml file has a cs file where all the backend code runs, i was able to generate as many textboxes i needed and direct all of them to a single function, but this function stills on the cs file attached to the xaml parent, is it possible to allocate this function in an utility class? otherwise i will have to place the same code on every cs file.
something like:
```
<TextBox 
x:Name="txt_endRange" 
PreviewKeyDown="CLASSESS\UTILITIES.CS\PreventChars_PreviewKeyDown" />
```
thanks in advance